# How to keep image place until the image Loaded

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following code:

```
<img src="images/icon.png" /> <span class="status-error"> some text </span>
```

The problem:

Before the image loaded, or after rendering the whole line (itemview), the text comes in the image place, and only when the image loaded - the text jumps to the right side.

I tried with `position:absolute`, but it made ​​a big mess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a proper height/width on your images and they will reserve the space even before loading.

```
<img src="images/icon.png" height="16" width="16" />
```